# Power BI: Using Secondary Relationship in Separate Report/Tab

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

Please see a screenshot of my data model below:

[image: Data model here]

At present, all slicers filter based on the relationship between the Fiscal Year Table and the facts table's "Date Received" column. This is the primary relationship.

There are a total of three reports/tabs in my dashboard. For only one of those tabs, I would like to slice the data using the Fiscal Year Table's secondary relationship with the facts table's "Date Closed by GC" column.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure and use CALCULATE and USERELATIONSHIP() to switch to the desired relationship.

https://dax.guide/userelationship/

Comment: BINGO! Thank you!